# Change Windows permissions on single registry key

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry

Is there a way to restrict access to a single registry key for a specific application? Dropbox keeps resetting my shell overlay icons on every update and it's driving me bonkers (well it got a bit better after I found out that you can actually bookmark keys in the registry editor).

Still, is there a way to prevent an application with a specific path or executable name or something from writing to a single key (I don't want to disallow everything as I don't know if that'll break anything else).

Comment: Right click on the Key and select Permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do it for a specific app, per se. You can do it for a specific security identifier (SID), and then any app with that SID can't modify the key, but generally any program running in your user account will run with your SID, unless it's specifically being sandboxed.

With that said, it should break anything to remove write access from your account on that key. Leave read access, of course. You can always restore it later; Regedit runs with Admin privs.

Comment: Thanks, yes I guess just removing write permissions for my whole account should be OK too - I think the updater doesn't run with elevated permissions. I'll try.